# INTERNAL_IPS and ALLOWED_HOSTS in django settings

Tags: python, django

What is INTERNAL_IPS and ALLOWED_HOSTS in django settings.Why we are using it,what happen if we not use it.

Comment: It's a good idea to start with Django's excellent [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#internal-ips) before asking here.

Comment: @solarissmoke what if they read it and needed more understanding? like in "plain English". Do not assume everybody's first language is English and that if they read the same thing you read, they will come away with the same understanding as you.

Answer (score 3):

**`ALLOWED_HOSTS`**: It is a whitelist of host/domain names that your web server can be served on. It is a  mechanism to stop HTTP Host header attacks, which are nevertheless possible under many setups of web servers that seem to be secure. Hence, it is risky to use `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]` as it allows any host to server your webserver. Instead, you want to list it in your production environment as **`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.io', 'example.com', 'example.prod.com']`**. where these values are hostnames known to you, websites that handle the value of the Host header in a risky manner are targets of HTTP Host header attacks. An attacker may utilize this input to inject dangerous payloads that alter server-side behavior if the server fails to verify or escape it properly and implicitly trusts the Host header. Hence avoid using **`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]`** at all costs.

For

**`INTERNAL_IPS`**: It is also a whitelist of IP ADDRESS names that your web server can share sensitive information or exhibit a custom behavior. This Django setting is basically a filter that you can configure to consider a range of IP addresses. To get a practical use case,  You can install the [django-debug-toolbar](https://pypi.org/project/django-debug-toolbar/). Your web server can have a different behavior i.e having a popup in your test environment IP ADDRESS displaying sensitive information within its requests and debug output.

I hope this explanation was helpful. I do not think the documentation did give a satisfactory explanation but from experience, I am able to give this response.

Answer (score 0):

from docs:

**[INTERNAL_IPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#internal-ips)**

```
Default: [] (Empty list)
```

> A list of IP addresses, as strings, that:
>
> Allow the debug() context processor to add some variables to the
>   template context. Can use the admindocs bookmarklets even if not
>   logged in as a staff user. Are marked as “internal” (as opposed to
>   “EXTERNAL”) in AdminEmailHandler emails.

**[ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)**

```
Default: [] (Empty list)
```

> A list of strings representing the host/domain names that this Django
>   site can serve. This is a security measure to prevent HTTP Host header
>   attacks, which are possible even under many seemingly-safe web server
>   configurations.

Comment: not so useful to copy the docs without explaining them, the OP can just read it there and it will probably be more up to date.